# Customizing UITextField for Currency format works well with iOS 4.x but in iOS 5 gives null

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am customizing UItextField for local currency symbol and comma, using following link :

http://www.thepensiveprogrammer.com/2010/03/customizing-uitextfield-formatting-for.html

```
NSNumber *actualNumber = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:[mstring
                                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:localeSeparator withString:@""]];
```

**In iOS 5 this actual number is always null and in iOS 4.x it is working fine**

My code's main method for this purpose is :

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.tag == 1)
    {
        if(true)
        {
            NSMutableString* mstring = [[textField text] mutableCopy];
            if([mstring length] == 0)
            {
                //special case...nothing in the field yet, so set a currency symbol first
                [mstring appendString:[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol]];

                //now append the replacement string
                [mstring appendString:string];
            }
            else
            {
                //adding a char or deleting?
                if([string length] > 0)
                {
                    [mstring insertString:string atIndex:range.location];
                }
                else 
                {
                    //delete case - the length of replacement string is zero for a delete
                    [mstring deleteCharactersInRange:range];
                }
            }

            NSString* localeSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale]
                                         objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];

            NSNumber *actualNumber = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:[mstring
                                                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:localeSeparator
                                                                    withString:@""]];
            NSLog(@"%@",actualNumber);

            [textField setText:[currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:actualNumber]];

            [mstring release];
        }

        //always return no since we are manually changing the text field
        return NO; 
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

and This is the initialization

```
NSLocale *paklocal = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_PAK"] autorelease];
currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:paklocal];

NSMutableCharacterSet *numberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[numberSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
nonNumberSet = [[numberSet invertedSet] retain];
[numberSet release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're having a problem because `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` adds the currency symbol for `[NSLocale currentLocale]`, which may be different from the locale used by `currencyFormatter`.  In the simulator on my computer, it added $ (dollar) signs, to `mstring`, which were logically enough rejected by currencyFormatter.

When you construct `paklocal`, store it along with `currencyFormatter` and use it instead of `[NSLocale currentLocale]`.

If you have further trouble with `currencyFormatter`, use `NSLog` to display the string you send into it.